# How can we prove the tensor-product basis $\{|j_1,m_1⟩|j_2,m_2⟩\}$ is linearly independent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, atomic-physics

My reference is Walter Johnson's Book [*Lectures on Atomic Physics*](https://www3.nd.edu/~johnson/Publications/book.pdf) (2006).

Given our coupled $J$'s in the equation bellow:

$$m|j,m\rangle = \sum_{m1,m2}(m1 + m2)C(j_1,j_2,j;m_1,m_2,m)|j_1,m_1\rangle|j_2,m_2\rangle$$

Where $C(j_1,j_2,j;m_1,m_2,m)$ is the Clebsch-Gordan coeffecients, how can we prove that the eigenstates $|j_1,m_1\rangle|j_2,m_2\rangle$  are linearly independent and how can one conclude that:

$$(m_1+m_2-m)C(j_1,j_2,j;m_1,m_2,m)=0$$

is a requirement for the Clebsch-Gordan coeffecients to not vanish? This is stated, as if this is obvious (which it's not) on page 12 first line of the reference material I provided in the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This boils down to how you define the tensor product space 
$$
\mathcal H = \mathcal H_1 \otimes \mathcal H_2 = \mathrm{span}\{|j_1,m_1\rangle \}_{m_1} \otimes  \mathrm{span}\{ |j_2,m_2\rangle \}_{m_2},
$$
and how much you want to delve into its properties.

If you really want it in full, it's easier to take a slightly more abstract notation (so, consider vector spaces $V$ and $W$ with bases $\{v_i:i=1,\ldots,n\}$ and $\{w_j:j=1,\ldots,m\}$ respectively) and characterize the tensor product using its [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property).*

So, consider such a tensor product, and let $a_{ij}\in F$ be scalars such that
$$
x=\sum_{i,j} a_{ij} v_i \otimes w_j = 0.
$$
Now, consider $i_0$ such that $1\leq i_0\leq n$: for this index, there exists a linear map $f_{i_0}:V\to F$ such that $f_{i_0}(v_{i_0}) = 1$ while $f_{i_0}(v_i) = 0$ if $i\neq i_0$. (Why? this is basically the relevant element of the dual basis to $\{v_i\}$.)

Given this $f_{i_0}$, build $g_{i_0}=:V\times W \to Z=W$ given by 
$$g_{i_0}(v,w) = f_{i_0}(v)w.$$
For this map, we know that there exists $h_{i_0}:V\otimes W\to W$ such that $g_{i_0} = h_{i_0} \otimes \varphi$, in terms of the canonical bilinear form $\varphi:V\times W \to V\otimes W$ with $\varphi(v,w) = v\otimes w$. If we apply this $h_{i_0}$ to $x$, we get
\begin{align}
h_{i_0}(x)
& = h_{i_0}\left(\sum_{i,j} a_{ij} v_i \otimes w_j\right)
\\ & = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} h_{i_0}\left(v_i \otimes w_j\right)
\\ & = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} h_{i_0}\left(\varphi(v_i ,w_j)\right)
\\ & = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} g_{i_0}\left(v_i ,w_j\right)
\\ & = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} f_{i_0}(v_i) w_j
\\ & = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} \delta_{i,i_0} w_j
\\ & = \sum_{j} a_{i_0j} w_j,
\end{align}
and since $h_{i_0}(x)=h_{i_0}(0)=0$, we have $\sum_{j} a_{i_0j} w_j=0$ for the linearly-independent $\{w_j\}$, so we conclude that
$$
a_{i_0j} = 0 \quad \forall j=1,\ldots ,m,
$$
for any arbitrary $i_0=1,\ldots,n$. That concludes the proof.

---

<sup>* why? because it's the most broadly applicable - the universal property holds no matter what definition of the tensor product you want to use. If you want an argument which relies on a specific definition, then start from there.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is quite obvious.  How can $\vert j_1m_1\rangle\vert j_2 m_2\rangle$ be linearly dependent from $\vert j_1M_1\vert j_2 M_2\rangle$ with $m_1\ne M_1$ and $m_2\ne M_2$ since this would entail that
$\left[\langle j_1m_1\vert \langle j_2 m_2\vert\right]\vert j_1 M_1\rangle \vert j_2 M_2\rangle\ne 0$ for $m_1\ne M_1$ and $m_2\ne M_2$?

Now clearly since you will have $m=m_1+m_2$ you can certainly conclude that your left hand side is $0$ but this does not guarantee that the CG is itself non-zero.  For instance $(2,1,2;0,0,0)=0$.

Comment: This is only 'obvious' insofar as it's obvious that it is possible to set up a consistent, non-degenerate inner product on the tensor-product basis, which requires that the tensor-product basis be linearly independent. It depends on what exactly you allow yourself to assume, but there's a nontrivial chance that this justification simply hides a circular argument.